# C# Loading assemblies from internal resources

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I'm currently using the below code within a winform which is generated and compiled programmatically by another application, during this process I embed an assembly in the winform's resources so that it doesn't need an external reference. The the below code is called whenever we attempt to resolve an assembly and instead loads it from the resources.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {

   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." +

  new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {

  Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

  stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

  return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);

   }

};
```

The problem however is that this only seems to work in .net 4 and ideally I need this to work in .net 2 so that the created winform can be sent to clients, as the .net 2 framework is installed with windows but .net 4 is not. How could I achieve the same result in .net 2?

Comment: What happens when you try it in .NET 2?

Comment: Don't make us guess at what goes wrong on .NET 2.0

Comment: The code doesn't compile it it throws errors where the closing brace is and where the => is.

Comment: What's the version of .Net of the assembly?

Comment: The assembly itself it .Net 2, I've used it in another .Net 2 application and had no issues with it at all.

Comment: You can use VS2010 to write .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda syntax is not supported by C# 2. Use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += delegate(object sender, AssemblyResolveEventArgs args) {
    ...
};
```